# Forcing Empty CDATA Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, cdata

I was questioned if i could transform an xml by using xsl (1.0) but with keeping the CDATA elements even if there is no content in it. As xsl beginner i am a little bit overwhelmed by that question...

here is a simple sample.

**what i have**

```
<AMOUNT/>
```

**what i want**

```
<AMOUNT><![CDATA[]]></AMOUNT>
```

- is there a way to force empty cdata segments with no content?
- Is there a way to do it for all elements in the file?
- Is there a way to do it just for the ones in the **cdata-section-elements**?

(have a look at the AMOUNT element)

**here is my sample xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
    <Artikel>
        <Temp>
            <Zeile>107</Zeile>
            <Artikelzubehoerdaten>
                <Artikelzubehoerdaten>
                    <ZubehoerID>18</ZubehoerID>
                    <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                    <UrsprungsArt>1</UrsprungsArt>
                    <Ursprungsnummer>99100091</Ursprungsnummer>
                    <UrsprungsAuspraegungID>0</UrsprungsAuspraegungID>
                    <ZubehoerArt>1</ZubehoerArt>
                    <Zubehoernummer>00500041</Zubehoernummer>
                    <ZubehoerAuspraegungID>0</ZubehoerAuspraegungID>
                    <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                    <Mengenberechnung>1</Mengenberechnung>
                    <MengenFaktor>1.0000</MengenFaktor>
                    <Basismengeneinheit>Stk</Basismengeneinheit>
                    <Preisgrundlagen>2</Preisgrundlagen>
                    <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                    <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                    <Timestamp>AAAAAAAEbVw=</Timestamp>
                    <Gruppendaten/>
                </Artikelzubehoerdaten>
                <Artikelzubehoerdaten>
                    <ZubehoerID>19</ZubehoerID>
                    <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                    <UrsprungsArt>1</UrsprungsArt>
                    <Ursprungsnummer>99100091</Ursprungsnummer>
                    <UrsprungsAuspraegungID>0</UrsprungsAuspraegungID>
                    <ZubehoerArt>2</ZubehoerArt>
                    <Zubehoernummer>100</Zubehoernummer>
                    <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                    <Mengenberechnung>0</Mengenberechnung>
                    <MengenFaktor>0.0000</MengenFaktor>
                    <Preisgrundlagen>0</Preisgrundlagen>
                    <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                    <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                    <Timestamp>AAAAAAAEbWA=</Timestamp>
                    <Gruppendaten>
                        <ZubehoerID>1</ZubehoerID>
                        <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                        <UrsprungsArt>2</UrsprungsArt>
                        <Ursprungsnummer>100</Ursprungsnummer>
                        <ZubehoerArt>1</ZubehoerArt>
                        <Zubehoernummer>10300003</Zubehoernummer>
                        <ZubehoerAuspraegungID>0</ZubehoerAuspraegungID>
                        <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                        <Mengenberechnung>2</Mengenberechnung>
                        <MengenFaktor>1.0000</MengenFaktor>
                        <Basismengeneinheit>Stk</Basismengeneinheit>
                        <Preisgrundlagen>2</Preisgrundlagen>
                        <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                        <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                        <Timestamp>AAAAAAABuBI=</Timestamp>
                    </Gruppendaten>
                    <Gruppendaten>
                        <ZubehoerID>2</ZubehoerID>
                        <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                        <UrsprungsArt>2</UrsprungsArt>
                        <Ursprungsnummer>100</Ursprungsnummer>
                        <ZubehoerArt>1</ZubehoerArt>
                        <Zubehoernummer>10300001</Zubehoernummer>
                        <ZubehoerAuspraegungID>0</ZubehoerAuspraegungID>
                        <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                        <Mengenberechnung>2</Mengenberechnung>
                        <MengenFaktor>1.0000</MengenFaktor>
                        <Basismengeneinheit>Stk</Basismengeneinheit>
                        <Preisgrundlagen>2</Preisgrundlagen>
                        <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                        <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                        <Timestamp>AAAAAAABuBM=</Timestamp>
                    </Gruppendaten>
                    <Gruppendaten>
                        <ZubehoerID>3</ZubehoerID>
                        <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                        <UrsprungsArt>2</UrsprungsArt>
                        <Ursprungsnummer>100</Ursprungsnummer>
                        <ZubehoerArt>1</ZubehoerArt>
                        <Zubehoernummer>10300002</Zubehoernummer>
                        <ZubehoerAuspraegungID>0</ZubehoerAuspraegungID>
                        <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                        <Mengenberechnung>2</Mengenberechnung>
                        <MengenFaktor>1.0000</MengenFaktor>
                        <Basismengeneinheit>Stk</Basismengeneinheit>
                        <Preisgrundlagen>2</Preisgrundlagen>
                        <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                        <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                        <Timestamp>AAAAAAABuBQ=</Timestamp>
                    </Gruppendaten>
                </Artikelzubehoerdaten>
                <Artikelzubehoerdaten>
                    <ZubehoerID>21</ZubehoerID>
                    <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                    <UrsprungsArt>1</UrsprungsArt>
                    <Ursprungsnummer>99100091</Ursprungsnummer>
                    <UrsprungsAuspraegungID>0</UrsprungsAuspraegungID>
                    <ZubehoerArt>2</ZubehoerArt>
                    <Zubehoernummer>200</Zubehoernummer>
                    <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                    <Mengenberechnung>0</Mengenberechnung>
                    <MengenFaktor>0.0000</MengenFaktor>
                    <Preisgrundlagen>0</Preisgrundlagen>
                    <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                    <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                    <Timestamp>AAAAAAAEk3U=</Timestamp>
                    <Gruppendaten>
                        <ZubehoerID>20</ZubehoerID>
                        <Mandant>88</Mandant>
                        <UrsprungsArt>2</UrsprungsArt>
                        <Ursprungsnummer>200</Ursprungsnummer>
                        <ZubehoerArt>1</ZubehoerArt>
                        <Zubehoernummer>00200050</Zubehoernummer>
                        <ZubehoerAuspraegungID>0</ZubehoerAuspraegungID>
                        <Automatisch>0</Automatisch>
                        <Mengenberechnung>1</Mengenberechnung>
                        <MengenFaktor>1.0000</MengenFaktor>
                        <Basismengeneinheit>Stk</Basismengeneinheit>
                        <Preisgrundlagen>2</Preisgrundlagen>
                        <ManuellerPreis>0.0000</ManuellerPreis>
                        <PreislisteID>0</PreislisteID>
                        <Timestamp>AAAAAAAEk3I=</Timestamp>
                    </Gruppendaten>
                </Artikelzubehoerdaten>
            </Artikelzubehoerdaten>
        </Temp>
    </Artikel>
```

**here is my sample xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements ="ARTICLE AUTO AMOUNT GROUP_NUMBER"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ARTICLE_LIST>
            <xsl:for-each select="Artikel/Temp">    
                <ARTICLE>
                    <CROSS_SELLINGS>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Artikelzubehoerdaten/Artikelzubehoerdaten[ZubehoerArt=1]">
                            <CROSS_SELLING>
                                <ARTICLE><xsl:value-of select="Zubehoernummer"/></ARTICLE>
                                <AUTO><xsl:value-of select="Automatisch"/></AUTO>
                                <GROUP_NUMBER></GROUP_NUMBER>
                                <AMOUNT><xsl:value-of select="MengenFaktor"/></AMOUNT>
                            </CROSS_SELLING>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Artikelzubehoerdaten/Artikelzubehoerdaten[ZubehoerArt=2]">
                            <xsl:for-each select="Gruppendaten">
                                <CROSS_SELLING>
                                    <ARTICLE><xsl:value-of select="Zubehoernummer"/></ARTICLE>
                                    <AUTO><xsl:value-of select="Automatisch"/></AUTO>
                                    <GROUP_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="Ursprungsnummer"/></GROUP_NUMBER>
                                    <AMOUNT></AMOUNT>
                                </CROSS_SELLING>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </CROSS_SELLINGS>
                </ARTICLE>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ARTICLE_LIST>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**here is the actual output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ARTICLE_LIST>
   <ARTICLE>
      <CROSS_SELLINGS>
         <CROSS_SELLING>
            <ARTICLE><![CDATA[00500041]]></ARTICLE>
            <AUTO><![CDATA[0]]></AUTO>
            <GROUP_NUMBER/>
            <AMOUNT><![CDATA[1.0000]]></AMOUNT>
         </CROSS_SELLING>
         <CROSS_SELLING>
            <ARTICLE><![CDATA[10300003]]></ARTICLE>
            <AUTO><![CDATA[0]]></AUTO>
            <GROUP_NUMBER><![CDATA[100]]></GROUP_NUMBER>
            <AMOUNT/>
         </CROSS_SELLING>
         <CROSS_SELLING>
            <ARTICLE><![CDATA[10300001]]></ARTICLE>
            <AUTO><![CDATA[0]]></AUTO>
            <GROUP_NUMBER><![CDATA[100]]></GROUP_NUMBER>
            <AMOUNT/>
         </CROSS_SELLING>
         <CROSS_SELLING>
            <ARTICLE><![CDATA[10300002]]></ARTICLE>
            <AUTO><![CDATA[0]]></AUTO>
            <GROUP_NUMBER><![CDATA[100]]></GROUP_NUMBER>
            <AMOUNT/>
         </CROSS_SELLING>
         <CROSS_SELLING>
            <ARTICLE><![CDATA[00200050]]></ARTICLE>
            <AUTO><![CDATA[0]]></AUTO>
            <GROUP_NUMBER><![CDATA[200]]></GROUP_NUMBER>
            <AMOUNT/>
         </CROSS_SELLING>
      </CROSS_SELLINGS>
   </ARTICLE>
</ARTICLE_LIST>
```

(these are just cutouts of the real files)

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? Why use CDATA sections at all?

Comment: i think the "guys on the other side" dont parse it as they should (maybe as text or something i dont know), my boss couldnt persuade them to correctly parse it, they need the cdata on all tags always even if its empty... so here am i :(

Comment: I've seen this before. Forcing CDATA sections in the source data means the program read on the other side doesn't have to be convert HTML encoded entities like "<" ">". It's pure laziness and makes the data file horribly complex. One could argue it would be better to adopt a simpler data format like CSV... Have fun with these guys they'll find other ways to make their problems yours :-)

Comment: you are right, these guys already did that more than one time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force an empty CDATA section you can do this:

```
<xsl:template name="empty-cdata">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

If you don't know whether the value is empty or not, you can use a conditional:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(.)">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="empty-cdata"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Which you can then wrap in a template:

```
<xsl:template name="cdata-value-of">
  <xsl:param name="value"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($value)">
      <!-- let cdata-section-elements take care of wrapping
           in a CDATA section if needed. Otherwise you will
           need to do string-replacement of ']]>' yourself. -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="empty-cdata"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Which you then use like so:

```
<AMOUNT>
  <xsl:call-template name="cdata-value-of">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="MengenFaktor"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</AMOUNT>
```

But again, **there should be no need for empty CDATA sections**--honestly there is no need for any CDATA sections anywhere in the document at all!  You see how it greatly complicates document production and consumption and increases document size (in your case) even though the XML Infoset of the document is exactly the same.

Also, remember you can't use CDATA sections inside attribute values, so make sure you never use `cdata-value-of` or `empty-cdata` to generate an attribute value or your XML will probably not be well-formed!

Comment: thank you, it worked, i needed to change `<xsl:template name="empty-cdata">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>` to `<xsl:template name="empty-cdata">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: That's strange, on my processor (libxslt/libxml2) only my version works. Yet another reason this is a bad idea I guess! Disable output escaping at your own peril!