# Is there any way to force JAVA to print empty CDATA within Elements?

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I know it's inproper but the company "on the other side", for some reasons, forces us to change such code:

```
<POZ />
```

into

```
<POZ><!CDATA[[]]></POZ>
```

I found [Forcing Empty CDATA Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585507/forcing-empty-cdata-elements) but it needs an additional XSL file to be attached and this is something I would like to avoid.

I tried trivial

```
Element poz = new Element("POZ");
CDATA cdataContent = new CDATA("");
poz.addContent(cdataContent);
```

but it - of course - generates simple

```
<POZ />
```

not the extended version I expect...

Is there a way to force JAVA to generate these CDATA sections within empty Elements?

Comment: I see two possibilities:  Either that is a bogus requirement (i.e., the person who wrote it does not understand XML), or else your customer/partner is using a home-grown parser that is only sort-of-but-not-really XML.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, no XML application should ever care about the difference between CDATA escapes and normal text, or the difference between a self-terminated empty element and one expressed with separate open and close tags. I'd strongly recommend beating up whoever is consuming this document to make them drop this requirement.

The DOM doesn't consider the concept of an empty text node meaningful, whether it's a CDATA Section or not. I'm not sure offhand whether any of the other XML APIs will let you generate an empty CDATA, but I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is no.

If you absolutely require this, I would recommend that you write a postprocesing stage which does a simple string replacement on the file to force it into the form you require.

Comment: Let me just echo what you said for emphasis:  There is no such thing as CDATA in the DOM.

Comment: keshlam: this is the last opportunity I take under consideration but I hate such solutions and I will fight against it as long as I only can :-)

Comment: CDATA exists in the DOM, as a subclass of Text nodes. *EMPTY* CDATA nodes normally doesn't exist, any more than an empty text node normally exists. You can manually create one by editing the DOM, but there is no requirement that it be retained when you normalize or serialize the DOM, or that its presence be retained/respected by any downstream processing of the XML -- just as said downstream processing may not (and these days typically doesn't) retain the distinction between CDATA Sections and any other kind of text.

Comment: Note: You _could_, of course, reimplement the serializer, or swipe an open-source version of it and modify it, to do what you want. So, yes, one can "force Java" to do this, in the same sense that you could persuade it to print any other syntax. But the fact that it isn't easy/standard is a strong hint that it isn't considered desirable by the folks maintaining the tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't persuade the recipient that using XML properly is a good idea, then emit

```
<POZ>[[[[[[CDATA]]]]]]</POZ>
```

from the Java app, and post-process it with sed or similar.

Comment: Yep. Folks are asking for a purely-syntactic detail; give 'em a purely-syntactic solution. If they complain, ask them why they think they need it in the first place.